# Combining groupBy, tranpose rows to object property and counting row

Tags: arrays, lodash, javascript-objects, reduce

I have this array of objects:

```
[
    {
        "vp": "VIHAB",
        "situacao": "Analisando manifestação  do notificado",
        "id": "267"
    },
    {
        "vp": "VIGOV",
        "situacao": "Concluído com proposição de ações corretivas",
        "id": "234"
    },
    {
        "vp": "VINOV",
        "situacao": "Concluído com proposição de ações corretivas",
        "id": "261"
    },
    {
        "vp": "VINOV",
        "situacao": "Concluído com proposição de ações corretivas",
        "id": "260"
    },
    {
        "vp": "VICAT",
        "situacao": "Concluído com proposição de ações corretivas",
        "id": "265"
    },
    {
        "vp": "VICAT",
        "situacao": "Concluído com proposição de ações corretivas",
        "id": "266"
    },
    {
        "vp": "VICAT",
        "situacao": "Concluído com proposição de ações corretivas",
        "id": "244"
    },
    {
        "vp": "VICAT",
        "situacao": "Concluído com proposição de ações corretivas",
        "id": "243"
    },
    {
        "vp": "VICAT",
        "situacao": "Concluído com proposição de ações corretivas",
        "id": "245"
    },
    {
        "vp": "VICAT",
        "situacao": "Concluído com proposição de ações corretivas",
        "id": "246"
    },
    {
        "vp": "VICAT",
        "situacao": "Concluído com proposição de ações corretivas",
        "id": "247"
    },
    {
        "vp": "VINOV",
        "situacao": "Concluído sem proposição de ações corretivas",
        "id": "263"
    },
    {
        "vp": "VINOV",
        "situacao": "Concluído sem proposição de ações corretivas",
        "id": "264"
    },
    {
        "vp": "VIRED",
        "situacao": "Concluído sem proposição de ações corretivas",
        "id": "253"
    },
    {
        "vp": "VICAT",
        "situacao": "Concluído sem proposição de ações corretivas",
        "id": "249"
    },
    {
        "vp": "VICAT",
        "situacao": "Concluído sem proposição de ações corretivas",
        "id": "250"
    },
    {
        "vp": "VINOV",
        "situacao": "Concluído sem proposição de ações corretivas",
        "id": "252"
    },
    {
        "vp": "VINOV",
        "situacao": "Concluído sem proposição de ações corretivas",
        "id": "251"
    },
    {
        "vp": "VINOV",
        "situacao": "Concluído sem proposição de ações corretivas",
        "id": "248"
    },
    {
        "vp": "VINOV",
        "situacao": "Concluído sem proposição de ações corretivas",
        "id": "237"
    },
    {
        "vp": "VICAT",
        "situacao": "Concluído sem proposição de ações corretivas",
        "id": "262"
    },
    {
        "vp": "VIRED",
        "situacao": "Concluído sem proposição de ações corretivas",
        "id": "254"
    },
    {
        "vp": "VICAT",
        "situacao": "Concluído sem proposição de ações corretivas",
        "id": "259"
    },
    {
        "vp": "VINOV",
        "situacao": "Concluído sem proposição de ações corretivas",
        "id": "255"
    },
    {
        "vp": "VINOV",
        "situacao": "Concluído sem proposição de ações corretivas",
        "id": "256"
    },
    {
        "vp": "VINOV",
        "situacao": "Concluído sem proposição de ações corretivas",
        "id": "257"
    },
    {
        "vp": "VINOV",
        "situacao": "Concluído sem proposição de ações corretivas",
        "id": "258"
    },
    {
        "vp": "VIHAB",
        "situacao": "Concluído com proposição de ações corretivas",
        "id": "226"
    },
    {
        "vp": "VINOV",
        "situacao": "Concluído sem notificação",
        "id": "236"
    },
    {
        "vp": "VICAT",
        "situacao": "Concluído sem proposição de ações corretivas",
        "id": "242"
    },
    {
        "vp": "VICAT",
        "situacao": "Concluído sem proposição de ações corretivas",
        "id": "240"
    },
    {
        "vp": "VICAT",
        "situacao": "Concluído sem proposição de ações corretivas",
        "id": "241"
    },
    {
        "vp": "VICAT",
        "situacao": "Concluído sem proposição de ações corretivas",
        "id": "239"
    },
    {
        "vp": "VICAT",
        "situacao": "Concluído sem proposição de ações corretivas",
        "id": "238"
    },
    {
        "vp": "VIGOV",
        "situacao": "Concluído com proposição de ações corretivas",
        "id": "221"
    },
    {
        "vp": "VIHAB",
        "situacao": "Concluído com proposição de ações corretivas",
        "id": "228"
    },
    {
        "vp": "VINOV",
        "situacao": "Concluído com proposição de ações corretivas",
        "id": "232"
    },
    {
        "vp": "VINOV",
        "situacao": "Concluído com proposição de ações corretivas",
        "id": "233"
    },
    {
        "vp": "VINOV",
        "situacao": "Concluído sem proposição de ações corretivas",
        "id": "231"
    },
    {
        "vp": "VICAT",
        "situacao": "Concluído sem notificação",
        "id": "235"
    },
    {
        "vp": "VILOP",
        "situacao": "Concluído com proposição de ações corretivas",
        "id": "229"
    },
    {
        "vp": "VICAT",
        "situacao": "Concluído sem proposição de ações corretivas",
        "id": "230"
    },
    {
        "vp": "VINOV",
        "situacao": "Concluído sem proposição de ações corretivas",
        "id": "223"
    },
    {
        "vp": "VINOV",
        "situacao": "Concluído com proposição de ações corretivas",
        "id": "219"
    },
    {
        "vp": "VINOV",
        "situacao": "Concluído com proposição de ações corretivas",
        "id": "227"
    },
    {
        "vp": "VINOV",
        "situacao": "Concluído sem proposição de ações corretivas",
        "id": "222"
    },
    {
        "vp": "VICOR",
        "situacao": "Aguardando manifestação de outros gestores",
        "id": "164"
    },
    {
        "vp": "VIHAB",
        "situacao": "Concluído com proposição de ações corretivas",
        "id": "217"
    },
    {
        "vp": "VINOV",
        "situacao": "Concluído com proposição de ações corretivas",
        "id": "218"
    },
    {
        "vp": "VINOV",
        "situacao": "Concluído sem proposição de ações corretivas",
        "id": "166"
    },
    {
        "vp": "VIMAR",
        "situacao": "Concluído sem proposição de ações corretivas",
        "id": "225"
    },
    {
        "vp": "VIRED",
        "situacao": "Concluído com proposição de ações corretivas",
        "id": "215"
    },
    {
        "vp": "VIRED",
        "situacao": "Concluído com proposição de ações corretivas",
        "id": "216"
    },
    {
        "vp": "VICAT",
        "situacao": "Concluído com proposição de ações corretivas",
        "id": "19"
    },
    {
        "vp": "VIMAR",
        "situacao": "Concluído sem proposição de ações corretivas",
        "id": "171"
    },
    {
        "vp": "VIMAR",
        "situacao": "Concluído sem proposição de ações corretivas",
        "id": "208"
    },
    {
        "vp": "VINOV",
        "situacao": "Concluído sem notificação",
        "id": "220"
    },
    {
        "vp": "VIMAR",
        "situacao": "Concluído com proposição de ações corretivas",
        "id": "212"
    },
    {
        "vp": "VIMAR",
        "situacao": "Concluído com proposição de ações corretivas",
        "id": "211"
    },
    {
        "vp": "VIHAB",
        "situacao": "Concluído com proposição de ações corretivas",
        "id": "207"
    },
    {
        "vp": "VINOV",
        "situacao": "Concluído sem proposição de ações corretivas",
        "id": "12"
    },
    {
        "vp": "VICAT",
        "situacao": "Concluído com proposição de ações corretivas",
        "id": "172"
    },
    {
        "vp": "VIGOV",
        "situacao": "Concluído com proposição de ações corretivas",
        "id": "10"
    },
    {
        "vp": "VIMAR",
        "situacao": "Concluído com proposição de ações corretivas",
        "id": "167"
    },
    {
        "vp": "VIHAB",
        "situacao": "Concluído com proposição de ações corretivas",
        "id": "151"
    },
    {
        "vp": "VIMAR",
        "situacao": "Concluído sem proposição de ações corretivas",
        "id": "152"
    },
    {
        "vp": "VIMAR",
        "situacao": "Concluído sem proposição de ações corretivas",
        "id": "153"
    },
    {
        "vp": "VICAT",
        "situacao": "Concluído com proposição de ações corretivas",
        "id": "147"
    },
    {
        "vp": "VICAT",
        "situacao": "Concluído com proposição de ações corretivas",
        "id": "148"
    },
    {
        "vp": "VINOV",
        "situacao": "Concluído com proposição de ações corretivas",
        "id": "154"
    },
    {
        "vp": "VINOV",
        "situacao": "Concluído com proposição de ações corretivas",
        "id": "150"
    },
    {
        "vp": "VINOV",
        "situacao": "Concluído com proposição de ações corretivas",
        "id": "137"
    },
    {
        "vp": "VIART",
        "situacao": "Concluído com proposição de ações corretivas",
        "id": "146"
    },
    {
        "vp": "VINOV",
        "situacao": "Concluído com proposição de ações corretivas",
        "id": "158"
    },
    {
        "vp": "VICAT",
        "situacao": "Concluído sem notificação",
        "id": "168"
    },
    {
        "vp": "VIHAB",
        "situacao": "Concluído sem proposição de ações corretivas",
        "id": "63"
    },
    {
        "vp": "VILOP",
        "situacao": "Concluído sem proposição de ações corretivas",
        "id": "145"
    },
    {
        "vp": "VIMAR",
        "situacao": "Concluído sem proposição de ações corretivas",
        "id": "122"
    },
    {
        "vp": "VIMAR",
        "situacao": "Concluído com proposição de ações corretivas",
        "id": "210"
    },
    {
        "vp": "VIMAR",
        "situacao": "Concluído sem proposição de ações corretivas",
        "id": "121"
    },
    {
        "vp": "VIMAR",
        "situacao": "Concluído com proposição de ações corretivas",
        "id": "209"
    },
    {
        "vp": "VIMAR",
        "situacao": "Concluído com proposição de ações corretivas",
        "id": "120"
    },
    {
        "vp": "VINOV",
        "situacao": "Concluído sem notificação",
        "id": "165"
    },
    {
        "vp": "VINOV",
        "situacao": "Concluído sem notificação",
        "id": "169"
    },
    {
        "vp": "VINOV",
        "situacao": "Concluído sem notificação",
        "id": "170"
    },
    {
        "vp": "VIGOV",
        "situacao": "Concluído com proposição de ações corretivas",
        "id": "136"
    },
    {
        "vp": "VIHAB",
        "situacao": "Concluído com proposição de ações corretivas",
        "id": "66"
    },
    {
        "vp": "VIHAB",
        "situacao": "Concluído sem proposição de ações corretivas",
        "id": "62"
    },
    {
        "vp": "VIHAB",
        "situacao": "Concluído sem proposição de ações corretivas",
        "id": "57"
    },
    {
        "vp": "VICAT",
        "situacao": "Concluído sem notificação",
        "id": "92"
    },
    {
        "vp": "VIGOV",
        "situacao": "Concluído sem notificação",
        "id": "79"
    },
    {
        "vp": "VINOV",
        "situacao": "Concluído sem notificação",
        "id": "29"
    },
    {
        "vp": "VILOP",
        "situacao": "Concluído sem notificação",
        "id": "160"
    },
    {
        "vp": "VILOP",
        "situacao": "Concluído sem notificação",
        "id": "159"
    },
    {
        "vp": "VILOP",
        "situacao": "Concluído sem notificação",
        "id": "143"
    },
    {
        "vp": "VILOP",
        "situacao": "Concluído sem notificação",
        "id": "144"
    },
    {
        "vp": "VINOV",
        "situacao": "Concluído sem proposição de ações corretivas",
        "id": "14"
    },
    {
        "vp": "VILOP",
        "situacao": "Concluído sem proposição de ações corretivas",
        "id": "80"
    },
    {
        "vp": "VIRED",
        "situacao": "Concluído com proposição de ações corretivas",
        "id": "114"
    },
    {
        "vp": "VILOP",
        "situacao": "Concluído com proposição de ações corretivas",
        "id": "113"
    },
    {
        "vp": "VICAT",
        "situacao": "Concluído sem proposição de ações corretivas",
        "id": "149"
    }
]
```

I need to create a new array of objects grouping by 'vp', transposing the values of "situacao" to a property and counting how many 'id' there are with the same status 'situacao' for the same 'vp', like this:

```
[
  {
    "vp": "VIHAB",
    "Analisando manifestação  do notificado": 1,
    "Concluído com proposição de ações corretivas": 5,
    "Concluído sem proposição de ações corretivas": 6,
  },
  {
    "vp": "VINOV",
    "Concluído com proposição de ações corretivas": 10,
    "Concluído sem proposição de ações corretivas": 11,
  },
]
```

Is there any way to do that? I've founded no explanation with this combinations

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have assign your array of objects to data variable.

```
var data = [
            {
                "vp": "VIHAB",
                "situacao": "Analisando manifestação  do notificado",
                "id": "267"
            },
            {
                "vp": "VIGOV",
                "situacao": "Concluído com proposição de ações corretivas",
                "id": "234"
            },
            {
                "vp": "VINOV",
                "situacao": "Concluído com proposição de ações corretivas",
                "id": "261"
            },
            {
                "vp": "VINOV",
                "situacao": "Concluído com proposição de ações corretivas",
                "id": "260"
            },
            {
                "vp": "VICAT",
                "situacao": "Concluído com proposição de ações corretivas",
                "id": "265"
            },
            {
                "vp": "VICAT",
                "situacao": "Concluído com proposição de ações corretivas",
                "id": "266"
            },
            {
                "vp": "VICAT",
                "situacao": "Concluído com proposição de ações corretivas",
                "id": "244"
            },
            {
                "vp": "VICAT",
                "situacao": "Concluído com proposição de ações corretivas",
                "id": "243"
            },
            {
                "vp": "VICAT",
                "situacao": "Concluído com proposição de ações corretivas",
                "id": "245"
            },
            {
                "vp": "VICAT",
                "situacao": "Concluído com proposição de ações corretivas",
                "id": "246"
            },
            {
                "vp": "VICAT",
                "situacao": "Concluído com proposição de ações corretivas",
                "id": "247"
            },
            {
                "vp": "VINOV",
                "situacao": "Concluído sem proposição de ações corretivas",
                "id": "263"
            },
            {
                "vp": "VINOV",
                "situacao": "Concluído sem proposição de ações corretivas",
                "id": "264"
            },
            {
                "vp": "VIRED",
                "situacao": "Concluído sem proposição de ações corretivas",
                "id": "253"
            },
            {
                "vp": "VICAT",
                "situacao": "Concluído sem proposição de ações corretivas",
                "id": "249"
            },
            {
                "vp": "VICAT",
                "situacao": "Concluído sem proposição de ações corretivas",
                "id": "250"
            },
            {
                "vp": "VINOV",
                "situacao": "Concluído sem proposição de ações corretivas",
                "id": "252"
            },
            {
                "vp": "VINOV",
                "situacao": "Concluído sem proposição de ações corretivas",
                "id": "251"
            },
            {
                "vp": "VINOV",
                "situacao": "Concluído sem proposição de ações corretivas",
                "id": "248"
            },
            {
                "vp": "VINOV",
                "situacao": "Concluído sem proposição de ações corretivas",
                "id": "237"
            },
            {
                "vp": "VICAT",
                "situacao": "Concluído sem proposição de ações corretivas",
                "id": "262"
            },
            {
                "vp": "VIRED",
                "situacao": "Concluído sem proposição de ações corretivas",
                "id": "254"
            },
            {
                "vp": "VICAT",
                "situacao": "Concluído sem proposição de ações corretivas",
                "id": "259"
            },
            {
                "vp": "VINOV",
                "situacao": "Concluído sem proposição de ações corretivas",
                "id": "255"
            },
            {
                "vp": "VINOV",
                "situacao": "Concluído sem proposição de ações corretivas",
                "id": "256"
            },
            {
                "vp": "VINOV",
                "situacao": "Concluído sem proposição de ações corretivas",
                "id": "257"
            },
            {
                "vp": "VINOV",
                "situacao": "Concluído sem proposição de ações corretivas",
                "id": "258"
            },
            {
                "vp": "VIHAB",
                "situacao": "Concluído com proposição de ações corretivas",
                "id": "226"
            },
            {
                "vp": "VINOV",
                "situacao": "Concluído sem notificação",
                "id": "236"
            },
            {
                "vp": "VICAT",
                "situacao": "Concluído sem proposição de ações corretivas",
                "id": "242"
            },
            {
                "vp": "VICAT",
                "situacao": "Concluído sem proposição de ações corretivas",
                "id": "240"
            },
            {
                "vp": "VICAT",
                "situacao": "Concluído sem proposição de ações corretivas",
                "id": "241"
            },
            {
                "vp": "VICAT",
                "situacao": "Concluído sem proposição de ações corretivas",
                "id": "239"
            },
            {
                "vp": "VICAT",
                "situacao": "Concluído sem proposição de ações corretivas",
                "id": "238"
            },
            {
                "vp": "VIGOV",
                "situacao": "Concluído com proposição de ações corretivas",
                "id": "221"
            },
            {
                "vp": "VIHAB",
                "situacao": "Concluído com proposição de ações corretivas",
                "id": "228"
            },
            {
                "vp": "VINOV",
                "situacao": "Concluído com proposição de ações corretivas",
                "id": "232"
            },
            {
                "vp": "VINOV",
                "situacao": "Concluído com proposição de ações corretivas",
                "id": "233"
            },
            {
                "vp": "VINOV",
                "situacao": "Concluído sem proposição de ações corretivas",
                "id": "231"
            },
            {
                "vp": "VICAT",
                "situacao": "Concluído sem notificação",
                "id": "235"
            },
            {
                "vp": "VILOP",
                "situacao": "Concluído com proposição de ações corretivas",
                "id": "229"
            },
            {
                "vp": "VICAT",
                "situacao": "Concluído sem proposição de ações corretivas",
                "id": "230"
            },
            {
                "vp": "VINOV",
                "situacao": "Concluído sem proposição de ações corretivas",
                "id": "223"
            },
            {
                "vp": "VINOV",
                "situacao": "Concluído com proposição de ações corretivas",
                "id": "219"
            },
            {
                "vp": "VINOV",
                "situacao": "Concluído com proposição de ações corretivas",
                "id": "227"
            },
            {
                "vp": "VINOV",
                "situacao": "Concluído sem proposição de ações corretivas",
                "id": "222"
            },
            {
                "vp": "VICOR",
                "situacao": "Aguardando manifestação de outros gestores",
                "id": "164"
            },
            {
                "vp": "VIHAB",
                "situacao": "Concluído com proposição de ações corretivas",
                "id": "217"
            },
            {
                "vp": "VINOV",
                "situacao": "Concluído com proposição de ações corretivas",
                "id": "218"
            },
            {
                "vp": "VINOV",
                "situacao": "Concluído sem proposição de ações corretivas",
                "id": "166"
            },
            {
                "vp": "VIMAR",
                "situacao": "Concluído sem proposição de ações corretivas",
                "id": "225"
            },
            {
                "vp": "VIRED",
                "situacao": "Concluído com proposição de ações corretivas",
                "id": "215"
            },
            {
                "vp": "VIRED",
                "situacao": "Concluído com proposição de ações corretivas",
                "id": "216"
            },
            {
                "vp": "VICAT",
                "situacao": "Concluído com proposição de ações corretivas",
                "id": "19"
            },
            {
                "vp": "VIMAR",
                "situacao": "Concluído sem proposição de ações corretivas",
                "id": "171"
            },
            {
                "vp": "VIMAR",
                "situacao": "Concluído sem proposição de ações corretivas",
                "id": "208"
            },
            {
                "vp": "VINOV",
                "situacao": "Concluído sem notificação",
                "id": "220"
            },
            {
                "vp": "VIMAR",
                "situacao": "Concluído com proposição de ações corretivas",
                "id": "212"
            },
            {
                "vp": "VIMAR",
                "situacao": "Concluído com proposição de ações corretivas",
                "id": "211"
            },
            {
                "vp": "VIHAB",
                "situacao": "Concluído com proposição de ações corretivas",
                "id": "207"
            },
            {
                "vp": "VINOV",
                "situacao": "Concluído sem proposição de ações corretivas",
                "id": "12"
            },
            {
                "vp": "VICAT",
                "situacao": "Concluído com proposição de ações corretivas",
                "id": "172"
            },
            {
                "vp": "VIGOV",
                "situacao": "Concluído com proposição de ações corretivas",
                "id": "10"
            },
            {
                "vp": "VIMAR",
                "situacao": "Concluído com proposição de ações corretivas",
                "id": "167"
            },
            {
                "vp": "VIHAB",
                "situacao": "Concluído com proposição de ações corretivas",
                "id": "151"
            },
            {
                "vp": "VIMAR",
                "situacao": "Concluído sem proposição de ações corretivas",
                "id": "152"
            },
            {
                "vp": "VIMAR",
                "situacao": "Concluído sem proposição de ações corretivas",
                "id": "153"
            },
            {
                "vp": "VICAT",
                "situacao": "Concluído com proposição de ações corretivas",
                "id": "147"
            },
            {
                "vp": "VICAT",
                "situacao": "Concluído com proposição de ações corretivas",
                "id": "148"
            },
            {
                "vp": "VINOV",
                "situacao": "Concluído com proposição de ações corretivas",
                "id": "154"
            },
            {
                "vp": "VINOV",
                "situacao": "Concluído com proposição de ações corretivas",
                "id": "150"
            },
            {
                "vp": "VINOV",
                "situacao": "Concluído com proposição de ações corretivas",
                "id": "137"
            },
            {
                "vp": "VIART",
                "situacao": "Concluído com proposição de ações corretivas",
                "id": "146"
            },
            {
                "vp": "VINOV",
                "situacao": "Concluído com proposição de ações corretivas",
                "id": "158"
            },
            {
                "vp": "VICAT",
                "situacao": "Concluído sem notificação",
                "id": "168"
            },
            {
                "vp": "VIHAB",
                "situacao": "Concluído sem proposição de ações corretivas",
                "id": "63"
            },
            {
                "vp": "VILOP",
                "situacao": "Concluído sem proposição de ações corretivas",
                "id": "145"
            },
            {
                "vp": "VIMAR",
                "situacao": "Concluído sem proposição de ações corretivas",
                "id": "122"
            },
            {
                "vp": "VIMAR",
                "situacao": "Concluído com proposição de ações corretivas",
                "id": "210"
            },
            {
                "vp": "VIMAR",
                "situacao": "Concluído sem proposição de ações corretivas",
                "id": "121"
            },
            {
                "vp": "VIMAR",
                "situacao": "Concluído com proposição de ações corretivas",
                "id": "209"
            },
            {
                "vp": "VIMAR",
                "situacao": "Concluído com proposição de ações corretivas",
                "id": "120"
            },
            {
                "vp": "VINOV",
                "situacao": "Concluído sem notificação",
                "id": "165"
            },
            {
                "vp": "VINOV",
                "situacao": "Concluído sem notificação",
                "id": "169"
            },
            {
                "vp": "VINOV",
                "situacao": "Concluído sem notificação",
                "id": "170"
            },
            {
                "vp": "VIGOV",
                "situacao": "Concluído com proposição de ações corretivas",
                "id": "136"
            },
            {
                "vp": "VIHAB",
                "situacao": "Concluído com proposição de ações corretivas",
                "id": "66"
            },
            {
                "vp": "VIHAB",
                "situacao": "Concluído sem proposição de ações corretivas",
                "id": "62"
            },
            {
                "vp": "VIHAB",
                "situacao": "Concluído sem proposição de ações corretivas",
                "id": "57"
            },
            {
                "vp": "VICAT",
                "situacao": "Concluído sem notificação",
                "id": "92"
            },
            {
                "vp": "VIGOV",
                "situacao": "Concluído sem notificação",
                "id": "79"
            },
            {
                "vp": "VINOV",
                "situacao": "Concluído sem notificação",
                "id": "29"
            },
            {
                "vp": "VILOP",
                "situacao": "Concluído sem notificação",
                "id": "160"
            },
            {
                "vp": "VILOP",
                "situacao": "Concluído sem notificação",
                "id": "159"
            },
            {
                "vp": "VILOP",
                "situacao": "Concluído sem notificação",
                "id": "143"
            },
            {
                "vp": "VILOP",
                "situacao": "Concluído sem notificação",
                "id": "144"
            },
            {
                "vp": "VINOV",
                "situacao": "Concluído sem proposição de ações corretivas",
                "id": "14"
            },
            {
                "vp": "VILOP",
                "situacao": "Concluído sem proposição de ações corretivas",
                "id": "80"
            },
            {
                "vp": "VIRED",
                "situacao": "Concluído com proposição de ações corretivas",
                "id": "114"
            },
            {
                "vp": "VILOP",
                "situacao": "Concluído com proposição de ações corretivas",
                "id": "113"
            },
            {
                "vp": "VICAT",
                "situacao": "Concluído sem proposição de ações corretivas",
                "id": "149"
            }
        ];
```

And code is

```
var result = _.map(_.groupBy(data, x => x.vp), (group) => _.merge({ vp: group[0].vp}, _.countBy(group, x => x.situacao)));
```

Output of this code is look like,

```
    [
   {
      "vp": "VIHAB",
      "Analisando manifestação  do notificado": 1,
      "Concluído com proposição de ações corretivas": 6,
      "Concluído sem proposição de ações corretivas": 3
   },
   {
      "vp": "VIGOV",
      "Concluído com proposição de ações corretivas": 4,
      "Concluído sem notificação": 1
   },
   {
      "vp": "VINOV",
      "Concluído com proposição de ações corretivas": 11,
      "Concluído sem proposição de ações corretivas": 16,
      "Concluído sem notificação": 6
   },
   {
      "vp": "VICAT",
      "Concluído com proposição de ações corretivas": 11,
      "Concluído sem proposição de ações corretivas": 11,
      "Concluído sem notificação": 3
   },
   {
      "vp": "VIRED",
      "Concluído sem proposição de ações corretivas": 2,
      "Concluído com proposição de ações corretivas": 3
   },
   {
      "vp": "VILOP",
      "Concluído com proposição de ações corretivas": 2,
      "Concluído sem proposição de ações corretivas": 2,
      "Concluído sem notificação": 4
   },
   {
      "vp": "VICOR",
      "Aguardando manifestação de outros gestores": 1
   },
   {
      "vp": "VIMAR",
      "Concluído sem proposição de ações corretivas": 7,
      "Concluído com proposição de ações corretivas": 6
   },
   {
      "vp": "VIART",
      "Concluído com proposição de ações corretivas": 1
   }
]
```